# Handling errors using Vlookup in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, vlookup

I am using a Vlookup in a VBA function as follows:

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(target_arg, table_arg, 2, False)
```

When an entry exists in the lookup table (table_arg), then all is well.

If an entry does not exist in the table, then the cell has a #Value! result.  I've tried to do some error trapping, but once the Vlookup doesn't find a value, the function exits and none of my code after the above statement is executed.

I would like to trap this case so that I can do additional processing before I exit the function.

Comment: Sorry about the duplication.  I saw that post and didn't notice the error trapping code of "On Error Resume Next".  I tried to create an error routine (On error goto), which only works in subs.

Comment: Make sure you reset the error handling after the vlookup with `On Error Goto 0` otherwise you may hide other errors that need to be fixed not skipped.